# Python script does not understand difference between DIRECTORY and FILE

Tags: python

Hello to everyone who could help !
The Python script below gives the following error

```
File "/var/www/lighttpd/example.com/CloudMining/cloudmining/lib/dirmap.py", line 104, in __getattr__
    return self._read(name)
File "/var/www/lighttpd/example.com/CloudMining/cloudmining/lib/dirmap.py", line 81, in _read
    raise AttributeError('No file named ' + name)
AttributeError: No file named public
```

The problem is that relating config to this script defines PUBLIC as a directory, not a file !

```
pub_dir = os.path.join(path, './public')
if os.path.exists(pub_dir):
    self.set_public_dir(pub_dir)
```

But script below read PUBLIC as a file - and gives the error.
All other issues with the script are OK, it understands structure, it opens the files in format like

```
app.add_stylesheets('/public/custom.css')
```

so all relative paths are working.
But the code below contains an error to read ./public directory as a FILE, not directory.

Will be obliged for any hint to try and correct an error - I even can't find what's wrong.

The "problematic" lines (as per debug) are 98-104 (approx)

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if self._cache is not None:
        if name not in self._cache:
            self._cache[name] = self._read(name)
        return self._cache[name]
    else:
        return self._read(name)
```

**and 65-81 (approx) - most of all exactly these lines calls the error**

```
def _read(self, name, reader=None):
    kind, path = self._lookup(name)
    if kind == 'dir':
        if path not in self._sub_dirs:
            self._sub_dirs[path] = DirectoryMapper(path,
                cache=self._cache is not None, readers=self._readers)
        return self._sub_dirs[path]
    elif kind == 'file':
        if not reader:
            ext = os.path.splitext(path)[-1]
            if ext in self._readers:
                reader = self._readers[ext]
            else:
                reader = self._readers.get('*', file_reader)
        return reader(path, **reader.func_dict.get('keywords', {}))
    else:
        raise AttributeError('No file named ' + name)
```

Full script is available [here](https://github.com/alexksikes/CloudMining/blob/master/cloudmining/lib/dirmap.py)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that relating config to this script defines PUBLIC as a directory, not a file !
>
> But script below read PUBLIC as a file - and gives the error.

Hm, your code gives the Attribute Error if kind is NOT file and NOT dir...

So I guess there is a different problem...

Are you sure that ./public ist the right point?

and the Stylesheets /public/custom..... Is it in root?

Comment: This is not an answer and rather another question. If you want to post a question you should probably comment and ask.

Comment: @drmariod - everything in right positions, believe me...the same script open and process config files - but just because there are EXACT references to the files like ./config/sphinx.conf or (as above) app.add_stylesheets('/public/custom.css').
So IT READS and understands structure, definitely !
But when we come to the moment when it applies to './public' - it says "AttributeError: No file named public"
PUBLIC is the DIRECTORY, why script above reads that as a FILE - this is the question !

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13, I wasn't allowed to make comments, so to write an answer was the only possibility...
I am wondering why it raises the AttributeError, so it has to be a different kind then 'dir' and 'file'. So maybe I didn't understood you 'kind' variable and why you think "why script above reads that as a FILE - this is the question !". To me it looks like 'kind' ether dir nor file... But ok, maybe I am wrong.